# Jensen's inequality proof

Tags: probability, inequality, entropy

The standard proof for Jensen's inequality using taylor expansion around a point $x_0$ involves using only first 3 terms of the Taylor series till $f^{\prime \prime}(x)$. Why are we able to ignore the higher degree terms in the proof? As far as I am aware, there is no assumption regarding the points being close so that the higher order terms vanish. The proof is listed here (page 24) - https://web.cse.msu.edu/~cse842/Papers/CoverThomas-Ch2.pdf

Any insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: I know Jensen's inequality and proofs and I haven't yet seen a proof that uses the derivatives up to 2nd degree, other than using the derivative-based definition of convexity. Can you link a proof along the lines you describe?

Comment: @user2566092 Added the proof in the main question.

Comment: I guess you are referring to Theorem 2.6.2 of the pdf you linked? In that proof, Taylor's theorem is not invoked at any point.

Comment: @PhoemueX I am talking about Theorem 2.6.1 on page 24

Comment: @karmanaut: We can ignore the higher order terms, since we are using Taylor's theorem (with the Langrange form of the remainder) as in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor's_theorem#Explicit_formulae_for_the_remainder. Note that we evaluate the second derivative at an (unspecified) point $x^\ast$ and not at $x$. Finally, I have never seen this statement refered to as "Jensens inequality". It is just a characterization of (2 times differentiable) convex functions.

Comment: Jensen's inequality holds for non differentiable, convex, functions. Thus it seems odd to promote proofs requiring the existence of the second derivative.